# removing min from a list and storing it in new one

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

i am getting AN ERROR SAYING : list assignment index out of range

```
my=[3,4,5,8,9,6,2,4,7,5,3,1]

x=[]

for i in range(0,len(my)-1):

    x[i]=min(my)
    print(x)
    my.remove(min(my))
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Um... As @John Zwinch says, you shouldn't modify what you are iterating. And, if you just want to removing min and insert it into a new one. Why do you need a loop?

```
x = []
minimal = min(my)
x.append(minimal)
my.remove(minimal)
```

Couldn't the code above achieve your purpose?

Comment: *"you shouldn't modify what you are iterating"*? They're not doing that.

Comment: @StefanPochmann OK, do you mean OP is iterating a `range` generator but not actually `my`? What ever...

Comment: Yes, what they're iterating is a `range` and they're not modifying it. That's not even possible, as it's immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
>>> my=[3,4,5,8,9,6,2,4,7,5,3,1]
>>> x=[min(my)]
>>> my.remove(min(my))
>>> my
[3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 6, 2, 4, 7, 5, 3]
>>> x
[1]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below line 
`theMin=min(my);
x.append(theMin);
my.remove(theMin)`
I use phone answer your question, I can't find the break line key, so hope you know the pythonic !

Answer (score 0):

Find `min` of `my`. Assign the value to a variable. Now store this value in `x`. Then, remove the same from `my` list.

```
>>> my = [3,4,5,8,9,6,2,4,7,5,3,1]
>>> my_min = min(my)
>>> x = [my_min]
>>> my.remove(my_min)
>>> my
[3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 6, 2, 4, 7, 5, 3]
>>> x
[1]
```

I advise you learn to use meaningful names for variables. To avoid confusion, I've not changed the names of your variables.